# Terraform looping in list of map

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Terraform module that produces a list of map output:

```
object_ids = [
  {
    "object_id" = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
    "upn" = "john@domain.com"
    "user" = "john"
  },
  {
    "object_id" = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
    "upn" = "martin@domain.com"
    "user" = "martin"
  },
]
```

Using a for_each I can loop on one value to build this resource:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "subread" {
    for_each = toset(module.user.map_object_ids[*].object_id)
    scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
    role_definition_name = "Reader"
    principal_id         = each.value
}
```

However I don't know how to loop on more than one value.

I tried the following for another resource requiring 2 different values from the output:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "contribrg" {
    scope                = [for map in module.user.map_object_ids[*]: "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}/resourceGroups/${lookup(map,"user")}"]
    role_definition_name = "Contributor"
    principal_id         = [for map in module.user.map_object_ids[*]: lookup(map,"object_id")]
}
```

Got the following errors :

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
module.user.map_object_ids is tuple with 2 elements
Inappropriate value for attribute "scope": string required.
Inappropriate value for attribute "principal_id": string required.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fundamental requirement of resource `for_each` is that the collection you are using must have one element per instance you want to create, so it isn't possible to repeat based on more than one value, but fortunately I think that isn't actually what you are asking here.

Instead, it seems like you want to have one instance for each element of `module.user.map_object_ids`, and so the only additional problem we need to deal with is that `for_each` expects to be given a map of objects rather than a list of objects, so it can use the map keys as the identifiers for each of the instances.

We can convert a list of objects into a map of objects by using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions), though we'll need to identify one of the attributes of the nested objects that will serve as the unique key for each element. I'm going to use `user` here because it seems like it's a good human-understandable, configuration-selected unique identifier:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "contribrg" {
  for_each = { for obj in module.user.map_object_ids : obj.user => obj }

  scope                = "${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id}/resourceGroups/${each.value.user}"
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = each.value.object_id
}
```

The `for` expression above will project your list of objects into a map of objects, like this:

```
{
  "john" = {
    "object_id" = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
    "upn" = "john@domain.com"
    "user" = "john"
  }
  "martin" = {
    "object_id" = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
    "upn" = "martin@domain.com"
    "user" = "martin"
  }
}
```

Then inside the resource argument expressions `each.key` will refer to the usernames (because they are now the keys) while `each.value` will refer to the objects, and so we can use `each.value.object_id` to get the corresponding object identifier.

From this, Terraform will plan to create resource instances with the following addresses:

- `azurerm_role_assignment.contribrg["john"]`
- `azurerm_role_assignment.contribrg["martin"]`

---

A side note: I found it a little confusing that your output is named `object_ids` when it isn't just returning ids. It might be clearer to name it `objects`.

Comment: Many thanks Martin for the thorough explanation with the solution.